# C++ emplace_back parameters

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

Here is a piece of code in my daily work. I just want to ask you if there is any difference between the two cases, especially in terms of performance.

```
std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > aVec;

// case 1
aVec.emplace_back("hello", "bonjour");

// case 2
aVec.emplace_back(std::pair("hello", "bonjour"));
```

Following question:

What about a std::list for these two cases?

Comment: Mostly the same as `std::pair<string, string> p{"hello", "bonjour"};` over `std::pair<string, string> p = std::pair<string, string>{"hello", "bonjour"};`.

Comment: `std::pair("hello", "bonjour")` is not valid C++11 BTW, `make_pair` or wait for C++17.

Comment: would not in 1st case pair constructed in place, and in second case temporary pair constructed and then moved into vector ? Or it will be optimized by compiler ?

Comment: In case 1 pair will be constructed in-place, in case 2 pair will be created on stack and copy-constructed in vector.

Comment: @Fan For `std::list`, they're same; the rationale for `emplace_back` is the same.

Answer (score 10):

[emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) will construct the element in-place, the argument passed in will be perfect-forwarded to the constructor for the element.

For the 1st case, conceptually only one step is needed, i.e. the appropriate constructor of `std::pair` will be invoked to construct the element directly in `vector`.

For the 2nd case, three steps is needed; (1) the appropriate [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) will be invoked to construct a temporary `std::pair`, (2) the element will be move constructed in `vector` in-place from the temporary `std::pair`, (3) the temporary `std::pair` is destroyed.

Comment: Ah, Ok, your explanation is very clear. So I suppose that 1st case is better on performance.

Comment: @Fan In concept it should be. In practice it depends on how heavy the move operation and destruction of `std::pair` are. From this point of view we can't conclude it until the performance evaluation.

Comment: Exactly as said by @songyuanyao. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7MxVXpobwdSnqAIf) a demonstration of what he is saying and a rough performance analysis.

Comment: Also the 2nd case is the same as what `push_back` would do.